# ContactApp suddently returning undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a triggered script that usually runs fine, however, it's now throwing an undefined error on getAddress().  Here's the code:

```
var churnGroup = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("Churn");
  var churnGroupContacts = churnGroup.getContacts();


  for(var m=0;m<churnGroupContacts.length;m++){
    var CME = churnGroupContacts[m].getEmails();  //<---TypeError: Cannot call method "getAddress" of undefined is being triggered on this line
    var emailTo = CME[0].getAddress();
    var emailSubject = "Daily Churn Report";
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailTo,
    subject: emailSubject,
    htmlBody: emailBody,
    inlineImages:emailImages});
  }

}
```

Has any sort of limit changed with ContactApp?  Thanks

Comment: Try Logger.log(CME); see what data getting print

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding try catch statement.

```
try {
   // your script code here
 } catch(e) {
   // if the script code throws an error,
   // do something with the error here
 }
```

Actually, there are instances wherein errors in Apps Script are being intercepted and dealt with by simply adding exception handling. Such as

- [Issue 5579](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5579) in google-apps-script-issues tracker
- [Handle Errors in Apps Script with Try and Catch](http://www.mousewhisperer.co.uk/drivebunny/handle-errors-in-apps-script-with-try-and-catch/)

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  For one reason or another one of the contacts was coming up with no e-mail even though there was one defined in the contact.  Fixed it and the error went away.